# How to group by / group_concat each set of results?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

Image we have a table like this:

**table1**

```
+----------+----------+--------+------------+
| position | epoc     | name   | value      |
+----------+----------+--------+------------+
|    1     |    1     |   A    |        v01 |
|    1     |    1     |   B    |        v02 |
|    1     |    1     |   C    |        v03 |
|    1     |    2     |   A    |        v04 |
|    1     |    2     |   B    |        v05 |
|    1     |    2     |   C    |        v06 |
|    1     |    3     |   A    |        v07 |
|    1     |    3     |   B    |        v08 |
|    1     |    3     |   C    |        v09 |
|    1     |    4     |   A    |        v10 |
|    1     |    4     |   B    |        v11 |
|    1     |    4     |   C    |        v12 |
|    2     |    5     |   A    |        v13 |
|    2     |    5     |   B    |        v14 |
|    2     |    5     |   C    |        v15 |
|    2     |    6     |   A    |        v16 |
|    2     |    6     |   B    |        v17 |
|    2     |    6     |   C    |        v18 |
|    2     |    7     |   A    |        v19 |
|    2     |    7     |   B    |        v20 |
|    2     |    7     |   C    |        v21 |
|    2     |    8     |   A    |        v22 |
|    2     |    8     |   B    |        v23 |
|    2     |    8     |   C    |        v24 |
+----------+----------+--------+------------+
```

I want to be able to  get this table:

**table2**

```
+----------+--------------------+
| position | value              |
+----------+--------------------+
|    1     |    v01,v02,v04,v05 |
|    2     |    v13,v14,v16,v17 | 
+----------+--------------------+
```

the conditions are:

- JUST the "value" of rows with "name" A OR B;
- JUST "epocs" that are the first 2 unique results in "position" (epoc 3,4,7,8 are discarded)
- GROUP by table1 position (for each position I want the concat of the values that match previous conditions)

Comment: SELECT group_concat(value), name FROM (SELECT '@'row := '@'row +1 AS rownum, position, value, name position FROM ( SELECT '@'row :=0) r, table1) s WHERE rownum %2=1  and name = "A" group by position;
This results in a table with just the first "name" value for each "position", and not with the set "name" < 2 first ones (or multiples). Also it doesn't give me the limit of "epocs", it returns all! the "epocs"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
select position, 
  group_concat(value order by overall_row_num) value
from
(
  select position,
      name,
      value,
      epoc,
       @num := if(@position = `position`, @num + 1, 1) as group_row_number,
       @position := `position` as dummy, 
      overall_row_num
  from
  (
    select position, name, 
      epoc, 
      value,
      @rn:=@rn+1 overall_row_num
    from t1, (SELECT @rn:=0) r
    where name in ('A', 'B')
    order by position, epoc
  ) x
  order by overall_row_num
) x1
where group_row_number <= 4
group by position
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30a44/38)

Comment: `order by position, epoc` inside `x` is mandatory, in other case it can fail [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30a44/30)